# Disable chunked transfer encoding in go without using content-length

Tags: http, go, server-sent-events, chunked-encoding

Is there a way to disable chunked transfer encoding in go without using a content-length?

It's for Server-Sent Events which can't have either.

Comment: Don't understand. Why can't it use chunked encoding?

Comment: @JulianReschke: SSE *can* use chunked encoding, but you may not want to in some cases: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6202#section-4.3

Comment: @JimB thanks for the pointer; I have to admit that I don't understand the warning (unless chunking leads to events being sent delayed, but that would simply a bug in the sending party).

Comment: @JulianReschke: As far as I know, the only real issue is that you can't rely on the chunks for application message framing, so in general chunked encoding is fine.

Comment: Raised issue wrt HTML spec: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/515

Answer (score 4):

Set the transfer encoding header to identity:

```
w.Header().Set("Transfer-Encoding", "identity")
```